# recyclerView vs 3 textview for list of 3 items?

Tags: android, performance, android-recyclerview

I have activity that has single post and small related posts block with max 3 related items (can be 0-3 items). And onClick it will go to all related posts.

What is better for performance: using recyclerview for this 3 items or manually set 3 textviews?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A recycler view is for dynamic list of content.

If you have fixed content, then there is no reason to use a recyclerview unless you need additional features from the recyclerview such as correlating a model to a row item or built in scrolling.

Otherwise, there is no reason to use a dynamic list for 3 known items. Just toggle your visibility of whatever one of the three you care to show.